# Kafka server Shutdown after continue wrting data to topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

when  i am writing data to kafka topic using spark Direct streaming 2.1, after some time kafka geting shutdown.

```
val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()     
 props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ip:9092")   
 props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")       
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

   val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, partition,compression key,message)
   producer.send(message)
```

Comment: What is an exception?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Too many open files, and log retaintion exception , use of  ulimit -a | grep "open files" and setting new  limit  by "sudo ulimit -n 4096" not worked for me. Thank you

Comment: You're confusing Scala with Spark. This code is not Spark. You need much more than 4096 file handle limit

Comment: message to above kafka producer is geting from Spark Direct Streaming.Producer has been embeded in spark direct streaming application.